# traceroute does not work, output is * * * but network is fine

Tags: networking

On my Linux box, `traceroute` does not work. The output is like this:

```
$ traceroute google.com

traceroute to google.com (209.85.231.104), 30 hops max, 52 byte packets
1  * * *
2  * * *
3  * * *
4  * * *
```

Can anyone tell me why it's not working? Any possible reasons behind it?

Answer (score 33):

By default, [`traceroute`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/traceroute.8.html) uses high UDP ports for tracing hosts. However, sometimes firewalls block these UDP ports.

Try to add the `-I` (uppercase i) parameter to the command line, eg:

```
traceroute -I www.google.it
```

This will use ICMP instead of UDP for tracing hosts.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use -T (tcp) or -U (udp) to bypass firewall.
Some routers/firewall don't let icmp echo pass trough, that's why you'd use those 2 to by pass them.
Anyway, contrary as stated in wikipedia, on my debian boxes traceroute still uses icmp packets and not udp.

**EDIT**

I was wrong...it uses udp...the icmp coming back are for an unreachable port...sorry

Comment: for macOS it would be -P TCP or -P UDP and -P ICMP would be the same as -I in shodanshok's answer.

Answer (score 1):

it could be that a firewall upstream from you is blocking the UDP packets
[Traceroute](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traceroute)

> On modern Unix-like operating systems, the traceroute utility by default uses UDP datagrams with destination ports numbering from 33434 to 33534.

Comment: I thought trace route used ICMP packets.  I did not know that unix based systems use UDP.  Learn something new everyday.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because icmp TIME_EXCEEDED answer is filtered by the router/firewall that you use as default gateway or by your Linux system itself